# How to display only searched results in the browser as response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection that I search through by using a value from an input field using the `$search` operator and it works, when I console log the `result` it shows me only those documents that match the search, but I want them to be visible on the endpoint `http://localhost:3001/search` as well, but currently I get all the documents listed, how can I list the result of the search? I am trying with `res.send(result);` but it does not work. Here is my attempt:

```
// Requiring the dependencies
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;
const itemRoutes = express.Router();
let Comment = require('./comment.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect(BASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true })

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function () {
  console.log('Connection to MongoDB established succesfully!');
});

let collection = connection.collection("posts_with_tags_test");
collection.createIndex(
  {
    postContent: 'text',
    title: 'text'
  }
);


itemRoutes.route('/search').post(async (req, res) => {
  let result = await connection.collection("posts_with_tags_test").find({
    $text: {
      $search: req.body.queryString
    }
  }).toArray();
  res.send(result);
  console.log(result)
});

app.use('/search', itemRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Server is running on' + ' ' + PORT);
})
```

and here is my input field:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Search extends Component {


    getSearchQuery = () => {

        const queryString = document.querySelector(
            ".search-input"
        ).value;

        axios.post("http://localhost:3001/search", {
            queryString: queryString,
        });

        console.log(queryString)
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="search-input"
                />
                <button type="submit" onClick={this.getSearchQuery}></button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just access localhost:3001/search from a browser, it won't be visible because you aren't sending the data { queryString: "sample" } to be used in the query as **req.body.queryString** unless you're using Postman

If you're accessing it from frontend, in your React component's getSearchQuery, try using **.then()** on your **axios.post()** to receive the response from your backend

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3001/search", {
    queryString: queryString,
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.data);
});
```